# value="${fn:escapeXml(true)}"/> Is it useful?

Tags: jsp, jstl

Have a quick question:

```
value="${fn:escapeXml(true)}"/>
```

This code above I am using it within a hidden input field as below in various forms

```
 <input type="hidden" name="Eatit" value="${fn:escapeXml(false)}"/>
```

I know this jstl function is useful in preventing xml injection within forms for strings. My question is can booleans/int be manipulated in the same way and is this a useful solution against hidden input value tampering?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is useless. Escaping the value is useful when it's an string which contains or could contain special characters needing to be escaped. The literal Strings `"true"` and `"false"` don't contain any such character, so escaping them is unnecessary.

Comment: Hi JB, Thats for the reply, that clears up things a good bit. A follow on to that would be could a outside element use this boolean element to put xml code within, could it be used to disrupt/manipulate?